# Multiple conditions in the for loop

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I have a requirement to write a batch file as mentioned below:

```
REM LIST OF TEST CASES

set TESTCASE_LIST=(TC_88888,TC_99999)

REM LIST OF TEST METHODS

set TESTMETHODS_LIST=(TC_88888_Test1_Read,TC_99999_Test2_Write)
```

I would like to take the first item from both the lists and perform an action by using both `TC_88888` and `TC_88888_Test1_Read`  and next time, `TC_99999` and `TC_99999_Test2_Write` and perform the action..

continue until end of the list... i have the total items in the both list around 30. 
number of items are same in both the lists.

this can be achieved using for loop with two conditional variables for accessing the two sets into two different variables and use them according to the need.  I am not sure whether this provison is available in the batch scripts? (other languages like C, C++ will provide the option to have the two conditions in the for loop)..

Please provide me the solution either with for loop or any alternative.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
REM LIST OF TEST CASES
set TESTCASE_LIST=(TC_88888,TC_99999)
REM LIST OF TEST METHODS
set TESTMETHODS_LIST=(TC_88888_Test1_Read,TC_99999_Test2_Write)

SET count=0
FOR %%i IN %TESTCASE_LIST% DO SET /a count+=1&SET $!count!=%%i
SET count=0
FOR %%i IN %TESTMETHODS_LIST% DO SET /a count+=1&CALL echo case %%$!count!%% with method %%i
GOTO :EOF
```

Simple enough - if that's the way you want to do it.

---

Modified in the light of further information

```dos
@ECHO OFF 
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: Setting variable established elsewhere
SET yymmdd_hhmmss=DATE_AND_TIME
SET file=FILENAME
REM LIST OF TEST CASES 
set TESTCASE_LIST=(TC_88888,TC_99999) 
REM LIST OF TEST METHODS 
set TESTMETHODS_LIST=(TC_88888_Test1_Read,TC_99999_Test2_Write) 
SET count=0 
FOR %%i IN %TESTCASE_LIST% DO SET /a count+=1&SET $!count!=%%i
SET count=0
FOR %%j IN %TESTMETHODS_LIST% DO ( 
 SET /a count+=1
 CALL SET case=%%$!count!%%
 SET method=%%j
 CALL :runtest
) 
GOTO :EOF
:runtest
SET trxfilename=%case%_%yymmdd_hhmmss%_%file%
ECHO "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\mstest123" /test:%method% /resultsfile:"D:\TestResults\%trxfilename%"
GOTO :EOF
```

Results:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\mstest123" /test:TC_88888_Test1_Read /resultsfile:"D:\TestResults\TC_88888_DATE_AND_TIME_FILENAME"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\mstest123" /test:TC_99999_Test2_Write /resultsfile:"D:\TestResults\TC_99999_DATE_AND_TIME_FILENAME"
```

Note that I've no idea where you are setting the date-and-time string or the filename.

Within the `runtest` routine, you can use `%var%` because it's running in the context of the subroutine, not the `for`.

You could also change to read

```
set ...list=whatever1,whatever2
for %%i in (%...list%) do ...
```

which may be more convenient. Actually, you could read the lists from a file if you'd prefer. That way, you could establish standard sets of tests, say `standard1` and `standard2` and then simply supply the standard-test-name to this snippet and maintain the test-set externally.

Lot easier andquicker if we have a handle on the entire scope of the problem rather than one specific aspect.

---

As it turns out, It would appear that the entire problem can be solved in one LOGICAL line:

```dos
for /f "tokens=1-2" %%a in (%templatefile%) do (
  ECHO "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\mstest123" /test:%%b /resultsfile:"D:\TestResults\%%a_%yymmdd_hhmmss%_%file%"
)
```

Where `file` and `yymmdd_hhmmss` are supplied and `templatefile` contains the name of a file which has lines

```
TC_88888,TC_88888_Test1_Read
TC_99999,TC_99999_Test2_Write
```

Change the template filename - change the set of tests applied. Want to change the number of parameters substituted in from each line in the template file? Change the `1-2` to `1-3` and the third parameter appears as `%%c`

Just a matter of specifying the problem, not the method.

Comment: the above solution works fine. i need to use those two variables

Comment: @ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
REM LIST OF TEST CASES
set TESTCASE_LIST=(TC_88888,TC_99999)
REM LIST OF TEST METHODS
set TESTMETHODS_LIST=(TC_88888_Test1_Read,TC_99999_Test2_Write)

SET count=0
FOR %%i IN %TESTCASE_LIST% DO SET /a count+=1&SET $!count!=%%i
SET count=0
FOR %%j IN %TESTMETHODS_LIST% DO (
SET /a count+=1&CALL echo case %%$!count!%% with method %%j
SET /a count+=1&SET $!count!=%%j_%%$!count!%% 
echo testid %%$!count!%%
echo method %%j
)  the first SET and echo are working but when i wated to use SET /a count+=1&SET $!count!=%%j_%%$!count!%% is failing. pls suggest

Comment: Is failing to do what? You'd need to explain what you intend to do since your method clearly isn't working. For instance, the first `for` sets `$1`,`$2` etc to the value from the case list. Your code would then assign to `$2` the value `TC_88888_Test1_Read_%$2%`. What do you actually want to show? or do you want to set variables like `case` and a corresponding `method` to be used in some manner?

Comment: Thanks for your response.yes, I wanted to use the variables 'case' and 'method' as shown below: SET trxfilename=case_%yymmdd_hhmmss%_%file% and then wanted to use "trxfilename" variable and method as shown:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\mstest123" /test:method /resultsfile:"D:\TestResults\%trxfilename%"

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. It solved my problem. excellent. Hope :: Setting variable established elsewhere
is very important to set the scope of the variables for entire script/file. Regarding the usage of the files instead of arrays/lists, Do you mean i can keep cases in one file and methods in another file and read them with for loops from files instead of lists. this would be more convenient for future expansion of test cases and methods witout modifying the batch script.Please through some more light of using files instead of lists. appreciate your time.

Comment: Lot better. I will give a try and let you know. Thanks for the solution

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution messing with delayed and double expansion.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set list1=a,b,c
set list2=1,2,3,$

for %%1 in (%list1%) do (
    set x=!list2!
    set list2=!list2:*,=!
    call set x2=%%x:,!list2!=%%
    echo %%1 !x2!
)
```

This displays:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

It can be easily adapted to your problem. Note the extra ",$" at the end of second list.

A second solution avoiding the double expansion and using cmd tokenizing ability:

```
for %%1 in (%list1%) do (
    for /F "delims=," %%2 in ("!list2!") do set x2=%%2
    set list2=!list2:*,=!
    echo %%1 !x2!
)
```

And finally, a solution fully using tokenization:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set list1=a,b,c
set list2=1,2,3

for %%1 in (%list1%) do (
    for /F "delims=, tokens=1*" %%2 in ("!list2!") do (
        echo %%1 %%2
        set list2=%%3
    )
)
```

Comment: using `%%1` and `%%2` etc as loop variables is confusing for people needing to learn batch scripting.  Please use a-z and A-Z variables.

Comment: I am unable to retrieve the items from the second list with above solution

Comment: @user3151144: edited to add missing declaration. Perhaps it will make it works for you.

Comment: I am using the below code for getting the Date and timestamp and using these variables to build other variables. For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
 For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set mytime=%%a%%b)
 
SET trxfilename=%case%_%mydate%%mytime%_%file%. I am getting the problem when time has a single digit like 1:00 to 9:00hrs. after the time crosses 10:00. the variables works fine... I want the script to work even when the time is less than 9:00hrs...Pls help on this

Comment: SET yymmdd_hhmmss=DATE_AND_TIME
SET trxfilename=%case%_%yymmdd_hhmmss%_%file%
 the above DATE_AND_TIME doesn't work when i use it to create a folder name with timestamp as it sees a space when hour changes from 9 to 10... no idea how to resolve the issue. the above script works only before 10 not after 10.

Comment: The extra space is probably in the %TIME% variable. Try something like echo [%TIME%] to check. If this is the case, use %TIME: =0% which replaces the space by a zero. I guess this could deserve its own question.